# XMLHttpRequest. Как отправить данные вместе с файлом.

Tags: php, javascript, formdata

Отправляю в php скрипт файл, используя XMLHttpRequest и FormData. Собственно, вопрос, как я могу вместе с файлов отправить еще какие-то данные вроде ID ?

```
const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
const formData = new FormData();

request.open('POST', 'composer/upload_photo.php');

formData.append('photo', file);

request.send(formData);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все просто вот так добавив еще значение в форму, и в зависимости от метода отправки доставать их или из POST или из GET, а файл из FILES

```
formData.append('id', id);
```

Comment: Я пытался. Но так и не сообразил, как потом это достать...

Comment: А вы на каком языке бекенд пишите? У меня лично все именно так и работает.

Comment: на свежую голову сообразил, и достал из $_POST, до этого сидел, и не понимал, почему айдишки нет в $_FILES...
Спасибо

Comment: Да из $_POST или $_GET нужно доставать в зависимости от способа доставки ))))